# How can I display items from a list in a vertical sort of style in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I want to take all of the items in a list I have made and display them as buttons going down by each item in PyQt5.

I tried a for loop and `QVBoxLayout`:

```
list_frame = QFrame()
layout = QBoxLayout()               
for item in my_list:
    layout.addWidget(item)
list_frame.setLayout(layout)
list_frame.show()
```

That did what I wanted but it made a new window and put them all there. How can I do it in the same window?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You need to add the `list_frame` to the layout of the window you already have.